# Copying specific chrome extension to another PC...google chrome suddenly deletes it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

If I go into:

`C:\Documents and Settings\MyUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`

I can see all the chrome extensions in various folders.  If I copy one of these folders into another users PC and open chrome on their PC that folder that I just copied is automatically deleted by chrome.

Is there some program / process that google chrome checks this folder and sees that a manual upload to this folder was made and deletes it? I want to be able to copy various extensions to other users PC just by copying the folders over.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome deletes any extensions that are installed 'underneath it' as it were (I.e. it wasn't aware of it) deliberately to stop 3rd party software from adding things like toolbars or adware without the users explicit approval.

If you want to move an extension around, you need to use "Load unpacked extension" from the extensions area of the chrome settings. You can't do it by just putting the files there on the hard disk.